# Declaring and filling a globel level dictionary variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, global-variables

So I have a dictionary that contains the same keys and values in two different subs in a module. That is to say there's some repeated code in the subs namely: Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary and Dict.Add Key, Value to fill it. I thought I should instead make the dictionary a global/module level variable, but am having trouble figuring out how to fill the dictionary at the larger scope.

The start of my module looks like:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text ' for some other stuff I need to do
Public Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
```

Just putting Dict.Add before any of the subs doesn't seem to work, I get a compile error: Invalid outside procedure.

Any tips or tricks would be much appreciated!

Comment: ?Set Dict as New Dictionary

Comment: The variable can be global, but the initialization can't - that has to be inside a procedure. I'd suggest a private `Function` that *returns* the filled `Dictionary` if the initialization is always the same.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Follow up question, if the private function returns the filled dictionary I need to call it inside the sub where I need the dictionary right? Or would running it once be enough to initialize the global variable?

Comment: @Jeeped It was based on this sentence in the question that implied the OP was trying to use `Dict.Add` outside a procedure: "Just putting Dict.Add before any of the subs doesn't seem to work, I get a compile error: Invalid outside procedure."  Based on that, it's absolutely correct.

Comment: @Comintern, Ah yes, I get it now. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've added Microsoft Scripting Runtime to the project references, this should work.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Sub d1()
    Dict.Item(1) = 2
End Sub

Sub da()
    Dict.Item("a") = "b"
End Sub
```

However, if you are expecting your public dictionary to have a dict.CompareMode of vbTextCompare, you would be wrong. The CompareMode property would be vbBinaryCompare and the CompareMode can only be set on an empty dictionary.

If you require vbTextCompare for your dictionary, then perhaps something like this.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Sub d1()
    if dict.count = 0 then dict.comparemode = vbtextcompare
    Dict.Item(1) = 2
End Sub

Sub da()
    if dict.count = 0 then dict.comparemode = vbtextcompare
    Dict.Item("a") = "b"
End Sub
```

Comment: I need vbTextCompare for some comparisons that aren't dictionary related so your first answer seems to work fine. I probably shouldn't have included it in the question to avoid confusion.

I'm not overly experienced using VBA, one of the commenters suggested using a private function which returns the filled dictionary. Is there an advantage to using a Sub instead? Or any particular reason why you used a Sub?

Comment: I suppose it (sub vs function) is a matter of personal choice. I only use functions when I want to return a calculated value. Using a function to populate a public dictionary without even returning the count seems like more of a job for a sub.